# Using NearestFunction in ParallelMap: why the slowdown?

Tags: parallelization

### Intro

I am trying to do various calculations (call some **Analyze[point, neighbourhood]** function) over the large datasets of points in 2D space. The nature of the calculations is irrelevant, but basic scenario is this:

- for each point we get all the neighbours within a certain window around it;
- apply the **Analyze[...]** function to the list of the neighbours.

I use **Nearest[...]** to generate **NearestFunction**, which I then apply to each point as needed to obtain list of neighbours.

### The problem

The issue is that I cannot parallelise it automatically. An example is below, with **Analyze[...]** reproducing the work of native **MeanShift[...]**:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 2}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 nf = Nearest[data]
 ]

Print["Native MeanShift[...]:"]
AbsoluteTiming[a = MeanShift[data, 0.1]; Short[a]]
Print["Serial Map of custom meanshift:"]
AbsoluteTiming[b = Map[Mean[nf[#, {All, 0.1}]] &, data]; Short[b]]
Print["ParallelMap of custom meanshift:"]
AbsoluteTiming[c = ParallelMap[Mean[nf[#, {All, 0.1}]] &, data];Short[c]]

Chop[a - b] // Norm
Chop[a - c] // Norm



"Native MeanShift[...]:"
Out[1853]= {0.196895,{{0.952903,0.197091},{0.401769,0.566927},<<9997>>,{0.0726459,0.558314}}}

"Serial Map of custom meanshift:"
Out[1855]= {0.316036,{{0.952903,0.197091},{0.401769,0.566927},<<9997>>,{0.0726459,0.558314}}}

"ParallelMap of custom meanshift:"
Out[1857]= {2.45064,{{0.952903,0.197091},{0.401769,0.566927},<<9997>>,{0.0726459,0.558314}}}

Out[1858]= 0
Out[1859]= 0
```

### Question

As you can see, the **ParallelMap** is slower than serial execution. Why? What are the actual guts of the **NearestFunction[...]** that in **ParallelMap** version it experiences a slowdown?

I'm guessing there might be some access conflicts, with different parallel kernels using their own automatically distributed copies of index function (if that what **NearestFunction[...]** is) but trying to access the global data list simultaneously.

If that's the case, what is the workaround – distribute the data itself and create nearest function within each parallel kernel?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: It might be faster if you use `DistributeDefinitions` on the `NerestFunction`. Also granularity matters here. If you divvy the data into chunks you might get improvment. But best is probably to take advantage of listability and do `Mean[nf[data, {All, 0.1}]] `. Under the hood the `NearstFunction` will use parallel mapping I believe.

Comment: Note that `MeanShift` is already parallelized (via the Math Kernel Library, probably).

Comment: Thank you!

Appreciate the tip about the listability in NearestFunction[] – it does perform better than mapping over the list of points. Unfortunately such listable call seems to be a recent addition: supported in v11, but not in v10 (at least not in Linux version I have access to).

Probably the issue in the question is the implicit parallelisation of NearestFunction[], just like the MeanShift. Then the attempt to use second layer of parallelisation via ParallelMap degrades the performance.

I wonder if one can restrict this "implicit" Math Kernel parallelisation?